# Why do inline elements behave like block level elements when floated?

Tags: css, css-float, language-lawyer

**Where in the CSS spec does it define this behavior?**

As stated in these two articles...

[Smashing Magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/#what-you-should-know-about-floats)

> When you float an element it becomes a block box

[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/float/)

> An element that is floated is automatically `display: block;`

---

**Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/kennethcss/y6cmgubt/

```css
a {
  /* for looks */
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;

  /* Comment "float: left" out to test. Once the float is removed, neither
   * the height or width have any effect on the anchor because its default
   * display is inline.
   */
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a>Nav Item 1</a>
  <a>Nav Item 2</a>
  <a>Nav Item 3</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is defined in the point 3 of this CSS2.1 section:

> ### [9.7 Relationships between `display`, `position`, and `float`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo)
>
> The three properties that affect box generation and layout — [`display`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display), [`position`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position), and [`float`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-float) — interact as follows:
>
> 1. If [`display`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display) has the value `none`, then [`position`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position) and [`float`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-float) do not apply. In this case, the element generates no box.
> 2. Otherwise, if [`position`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position) has the value `absolute` or `fixed`, the box is absolutely positioned, the computed value of [`float`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-float) is `none`, and display is set according to the table below. The position of the box will be determined by the [`top`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-top), [`right`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-right), [`bottom`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-bottom) and [`left`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-left) properties and the box's containing block.
> 3. Otherwise, if `float` has a value other than `none`, the box is floated and `display` is set according to the table below.
> 4. Otherwise, if the element is the root element, `display` is set according to the table below, except that it is undefined in CSS 2.1 whether a specified value of `list-item` becomes a computed value of `block` or `list-item`.
> 5. Otherwise, the remaining [`display`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display) property values apply as specified.
>
> ```
> ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
> ┃ #Specified value#                                        ┃ #Computed value# ┃
> ┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
> │ inline-table                                             │ table            │
> ├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────┤
> │ inline, table-row-group, table-column, table-column-group│ block            │
> │ table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row        │                  │
> │ table-cell, table-caption, inline-block                  │                  │
> ├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────┤
> │ others                                                   │ same as specified│
> └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────┘
> ```

In Display Level 3, this process is called **blockification**:

> ### [2.7. Automatic Box Type Transformations](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#transformations)
>
> Some layout effects require [*blockification*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#blockify) or [*inlinification*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#inlinify) of the box type, which sets the box’s [outer display type](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#outer-display-type), if it is not [`none`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-none) or [`contents`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-contents), to [`block`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-block) or [`inline`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-inline) (respectively).
>
> Some examples of this include:
>
> - Absolute positioning or floating an element [blockifies](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#blockify) the box’s display type. [CSS2]

Answer (score 2):

It's defined in the [**Visual Formatting Model section 9.5.1**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position)

> This property specifies whether a box should float to the left, right, or not at all. It may be set for any element, but only applies to elements that generate boxes that are not absolutely positioned. The values of this property have the following meanings:
>
> **left**
>
> The element generates a **block box** that is floated to the left. Content flows on the right side of the box, starting at the top (subject to the 'clear' property).
>
> **right**
>
> Similar to 'left', except the box is floated to the right, and content flows on the left side of the box, starting at the top.

Answer (score -1):

Its because `<a>` tag is inline element.
Look here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp
 It should help you,and if you create only `<a>` elements they are also will be floated inline: https://jsfiddle.net/r4r11d3h/

Comment: That's because `<nav>` elements are block level elements, however, `<a>` elements are not. So the fact that `<a>` elements take on the display properties of block elements when floated is peculiar. I'd like to understand why this happens per the spec or if it is just that, an oddity of CSS.

Comment: @KennethStoddard its  because <a> tag is inline element.
Look here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp it should help you,and if you create only a tags they also will be floated inline
https://jsfiddle.net/r4r11d3h/

Comment: @KennethStoddard do you understand now?

Comment: I'm afraid you are missing the point, I understand how block and inline level elements behave by default. I am trying to ascertain why inline elements act like block level elements when floated. Why is this behavior implicit? And to really stay on point, I am asking where this behavior is defined in the CSS spec.

Answer (score -1):

**Update:** I accepted this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38464859/why-do-inline-elements-become-block-level-elements-when-floated#38470721). The following is still good info and adds additional context to the discussion.

---

Here it is from the spec (in bold)...

> 9.4.1 Block formatting contexts
>
> **Floats, absolutely positioned elements, block containers** (such as inline-blocks, table-cells, and table-captions) that are not block boxes, and block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible' (except when that value has been propagated to the viewport) **establish new block formatting contexts** for their contents.
>
> In a block formatting context, boxes are laid out one after the other, vertically, beginning at the top of a containing block. The vertical distance between two sibling boxes is determined by the 'margin' properties. Vertical margins between adjacent block-level boxes in a block formatting context collapse.
>
> In a block formatting context, each box's left outer edge touches the left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting, right edges touch). This is true even in the presence of floats (although a box's line boxes may shrink due to the floats), unless the box establishes a new block formatting context (in which case the box itself may become narrower due to the floats).

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#block-formatting

---

Up-voted [@Paulie_D's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38464859/why-do-inline-elements-behave-like-block-level-elements-when-floated/38466491#38466491) because it does indeed point to a place in the CSS spec that authenticates this behavior, however, I did not accept his answer because it doesn't explain why this happens.

---

**Additional reading on Block Formatting Context:**

- https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-block-formatting-contexts-in-css/
- http://yuiblog.com/blog/2010/05/19/css-101-block-formatting-contexts/

Comment: Good try, but this is not right. You ask several questions that have slightly different answers. This answer is about Block Formatting Contexts, but as you can see from the quote BFCs can be established by inline level elements (inline-blocks) as well as block level elements. "An element that is floated is automatically display: block;" is defined by section 9.7 point 3 and the table that follows of CSS 2.1 - where you can see that it's not always true. "When you float an element it becomes a block box" is defined as per Paulie_D's answer. That all block boxes are block-level is section 9.2.1

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, your note concerning section 9.7 (point 3) is helpful. To be fair though, I only ask two questions. 1) Why do inline elements behave like block level elements when floated? 2) Where in the CSS spec does it define this behavior?

The two are interrelated. Adding additional comments to my answer.

Comment: I agree this can be misleading, but `display: block` is not a synonym of "establish new block formatting context". In fact, most `display: block` element do not establish a block formatting context, and things like `display: inline-block` do.

Comment: Hat tip to @Alohci for pretty much providing the answer in the comment above, I think the missing part was the reference to `Automatic Box Type Transformations`.