# overflow: hidden on non floating element causes it to shrink

Tags: html, css

I am wondering why the `overflow: hidden` property causes the border of the `<h2>` tag, *Who Knew CSS Had Such Power?*, to **not** appear underneath the right-floated `sidebar` `<div>`?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class='sidebar'>
    <h2>NOTE</h2>
    <p class="note">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est.</p>
</div>

<h2>Who Knew CSS Had Such Power?</h2>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores.</p>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
h2 {
    border-top: 2px solid rgb(141,165,22);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(141,165,22);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 30%;
     float: right;
     margin: 10px;
     background-color: rgb(250,235,199);
     padding: 10px 20px;
     border: 1px dotted rgb(252,101,18);
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/grqcth85/) is an example with overflow: hidden and [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/grqcth85/1/) is an example without overflow: hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, block boxes with `overflow: hidden` (or any other value than `visible`) establish new block formatting contexts. This has a number of [bizarre side effects with respect to floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943503/why-does-css2-1-define-overflow-values-other-than-visible-to-establish-a-new-b/11854515#11854515), one of which is exactly what you're seeing. From the link:

> Now if you apply an `overflow` value other than `visible` only to the second box, what a browser does is push *the entire box* aside to make way for the float, because the box now creates a new block formatting context that encloses its contents, instead of flowing around the float. This particular behavior is specified in the following [paragraph](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#bfc-next-to-float):
>
> > The border box of a table, a block-level replaced element, or an element in the normal flow that establishes a new block formatting context (such as an element with 'overflow' other than 'visible') must not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same block formatting context as the element itself. If necessary, implementations should clear the said element by placing it below any preceding floats, but may place it adjacent to such floats if there is sufficient space. They may even make the border box of said element narrower than defined by [section 10.3.3.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth) CSS2 does not define when a UA may put said element next to the float or by how much said element may become narrower.
>
> Here's what it looks like with `overflow: auto` for example:
>
> [image]
>
> Note that there is no clearance; if the second box had `clear: left` or `clear: both` it would be pushed *down*, not to the side, regardless of whether it established its own BFC.

The image depicts a somewhat different setup from what you have, but the principle is the same: an in-flow box that establishes a block formatting context must not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same block formatting context as itself. If this box is a block box with an auto width, it becomes narrower; otherwise, it's pushed either to the side (away from the float), or down if there is no room for the former.

Comment: Thanks. This line also helped: In a block formatting context, each box's left outer edge touches the left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting, right edges touch). This is true even in the presence of floats (although a box's line boxes may shrink due to the floats), unless the box establishes a new block formatting context (in which case the box itself may become narrower due to the floats)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `overflow: hidden;` creates new block formatting context

> **9.4.1 Block formatting contexts**
>
> Floats, absolutely positioned elements, block containers (such as
> inline-blocks, table-cells, and table-captions) that are not block
> boxes, and **block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible'** (except
> when that value has been propagated to the viewport) establish new
> block formatting contexts for their contents.
>
> In a block formatting context, boxes are laid out one after the other,
> vertically, beginning at the top of a containing block. The vertical
> distance between two sibling boxes is determined by the 'margin'
> properties. Vertical margins between adjacent block-level boxes in a
> block formatting context collapse.
>
> In a block formatting context, each box's left outer edge touches the
> left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting, right
> edges touch). This is true even in the presence of floats (although a
> box's line boxes may shrink due to the floats), **unless the box
> establishes a new block formatting context (in which case the box
> itself may become narrower due to the floats)**.
>
> https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#block-formatting

---

For additional context see this post...

[Why do inline elements behave like block level elements when floated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38464859/why-do-inline-elements-behave-like-block-level-elements-when-floated/38466731#38466731)

Comment: This has nothing to do with clearing floats. Were the float being cleared, you would see the outer h2 appear *underneath* the div.

Comment: Edited so as not to cause confusion, main point being though, that a new block formatting context is created by applying `overflow: hidden;` causing the two to sit adjacent. See this link for more details... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context

Comment: Cleaned this answer up a bit (though I had already linked to this info) for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score -1):

It is not that the over-flow hidden is affecting the H2 right border. You only had border properties set for the top and bottom of your H2 tag. You could fix this by either adding settings for right, right and left, or just blanket border properties.

```
/* border-right */
h2{
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(141,165,22);
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(141,165,22);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(141,165,22);
} 

/* border-right and border-left */
h2{
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(141,165,22);
  border-left: 2px solid rgb(141,165,22);
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(141,165,22);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(141,165,22);

}

/* blanket border */
h2{
  border: 2px solid rgb(141,165,22);
}
```

Comment: "It is not that the over-flow hidden is affecting the H2 right border." It absolutely is. The lack of side borders is completely irrelevant. You can very clearly see a margin separating the top and bottom borders of the h2 from the div only when the div is floated. That's where the side borders would have been.

Comment: That's not true. The only properties that are set for the border is for top and bottom. I doesn't matter if float or overflow is set, if you only set the top and bottom properties that's all you will get. I copied the code ad tested it.